# How to query top record group conditional on the counts and strings in a second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I call on the SQL Gods of the internet!! O so desperately need your help with this query, my livelyhood depends on it. I've solved it in Alteryx in like 2 minutes but i need to write this query in SQL and I am relatively new to the language in terms of complex blending and syntax.
Your help would be so appreciated!! :) xoxox I cant begin to describe

Using SSMS I need to use 2 tables 'searches' and 'events' to query...

1. the TOP 2 [user]s with the highest count of unique search ids in Table 'searches'
2. Condition that the [user]s in the list have at least 1 eventid in 'events' where [event type] starts with "great"

Here is an example of what needs to happen

[search event and end result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/914yg.png)

So the only pieces i have so far are below but boy oh boy please don't Laugh :(

What i was trying to do is..

1. select a table of unique users with the searchcounts from the search table
2. inner join selected table from 1 on userid with a table described in 3
3. create table of unique user ids with counts of events with [type] starting with "great"
4. Filter the inner joined table for the top 2 search counts from step 1

   SELECT userid, COUNT(*) as searchcount
   FROM searches
   GROUP BY userid
   INNER JOIN (SELECT userid, COUNT(*) as eventcount
   FROM events WHERE LEFT(type, 5) = "great" AND eventcount>0 Group by userid)
   ON searches.userid=events.userId

Obviously, this doesn't work at all!!! I think my structure is off and my method of filtering for "great" is errored. Also i dont know how to add the "top 2" clause to the search table query without affecting the inner join. This code needs to be fairly efficient so if you have a better more computationally efficient idea...I love you long time

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a helpful sacrifice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT top(2) userid, COUNT() as searchcount FROM searches 
where userid in (select userid from events where left(type, 5)='great')
GROUP BY userid
order by count() desc
```

hope above query will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `exists` and windows function `dense_rank` as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select u.userid, dense_rank() over (partition by u.userid order by count(*) desc) as rn
  From users u join searches s on u.userid = s.userid
 Where exists 
      (select 1 from events e
        Where e.userid = u.userid And LEFT(e.type, 5) = 'great')
 Group by u.userid  ) t Where rn <= 2
```